# Why include start-of-period values in first difference estimation?

Tags: econometrics, paneldata, first-difference

I am currently reading the [Paper of Dippel et al. (2015)](https://christiandippel.com/DGH_nberwp.pdf), where the authors estimate the causal effect of imports on voting behavior in Germany. Therefore, they estimate the following first-difference specification, where Yit refers to electoral outcomes, NetExposure refers to import - export exposure, τtr are time-varying fixed effects and Xit is a of control variables:

[image]

My question is why should I include "undifferenced" controls (Xit) in the first difference model?

Thank you in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to mix differenced and undifferenced variables. Just because dependent variable is differenced does not mean all variables have to be.

Typically you difference variables because:

- level variables have unit root
- you actually want to study differenced variables

However, if a variable is stationary and you are interested in an effect of the variable on dependent variable then there is no reason to include it in first differences.